# Android facebook sdk 3.0 logout not working?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook sdk 3.0 to login my application. login working fine. once i logout my application it's not happening.

my logout code:

```
Facebook mFb=new Facebook("xxxxxxxx");
mFb.logout(this);
```

give me some idea to do this.

Comment: If you're using 3.0, please do not use the Facebook class anymore. All the methods in that class have been deprecated. Please use the new Session mechanism.

Comment: ya... i done now working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ans: Working fine

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
@Override
public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state, Exception exception){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(session.isOpened()){
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(user!=null){
                    try{
                        session.close();
                        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                        //state.isClosed();
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(tag, "getUserIdMethod--->"+e);
                    }

                }
            }
        });                 
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 5):

I have been facing same problem finally i found this fix

```
public void logout()
{
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
    else
    {
        Session session2 = Session.openActiveSession((Activity)context, false, null);
        if(session2 != null)
            session2.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
    Session.setActiveSession(null);

}
```

I do not know whats going inside but i guess we will have to create new session if it is not found and clear token information for it.
It worked for me. hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if( mFb.isSessionValid() ) {                                  
    mFb.logout(getApplicationContext());
    SessionStore.clear(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook use:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

to logout.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to call it on separate thread:

```
public void logout()
    {
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mFacebook.logout(your_current_class_name.this);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
            }.start();
    }
```