# How to use facebook sdk logout method?

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I created mobile application and it includes two logging sections, called

Facebook login and
Normal login

In facebook login it use facebook credentials for app login,

In normal login user can register and login. when user creates account and it create session. fb login also creates session using fb sdk.

i want to remove this two sessions in one log out.

Can anyone tell me how to use fb logout method? then i can add it into my log out method.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687231/android-facebook-sdk-3-0-logout-not-working), seems that the line you are searching is session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();